# JQuery Accordion how to open particular header using script

Tags: jquery, header, accordion

I have created a accordion menu using the following code

```
<h3>Level 1</h3>
  <div>Content</div>
<h3>Level 2</h3>
  <div>Content</div>
<h3>Level 3</h3>
  <div>Content</div>
```

I want to open the different level headers using code. I tried looking into accordion and widgets code but could not find any function for this.

Please help me what code should be used to open a particular header. Also how to find if the head which should open is already open or not.

I also tried using

```
$("#rightMenuAccordion").activate('activate',1)
```

as listed [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#method-activate) but it says it does not exist

This is the code I am using to create accordion

```
<div id="rightMenuAccordion" 
    style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0px;top:0px;"></div>

$("#rightMenuAccordion").
    accordion({autoHeight: false, navigation: true, collapsible: false});
```

Comment: Please post the answer as a separate answer.  Do not edit the post.  Also, please elaborate on the answer, don't use a single line of code, provide some context.  I've edited the answer out, but you can [see the history for reference](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10024447/1).

Comment: please add a jsfiddle [www.jsfiddle.net] , that is proper way to debug the issue

Answer (score 3):

use activate() [FUNCTION](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion/activate)

see complete [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdAPh/)

NOTE: activate() method only works "collapsible:true"

```
$("#rightMenuAccordion").
    accordion({autoHeight: false, navigation: true, collapsible: true});

//by index
$("#rightMenuAccordion").accordion( "option", "active", 2 );

//OR header 
$("h3:last").accordion( "activate",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the accordion and pass the active header index to be opened

```
//setter for making the header be open on page load with active index value
$(".selector").accordion("option","active",activeIndex);
```

**Note**:`activeIndex` above should be an integer value and not string.
The first header starts from the index value 0.

Comment: Small note, if your accordion only has a single option (i.e. 1 index) you still need to set the active index = 0 or nothing will happen.

Comment: @DominicWoodman are you sure?..even if u just dont make the single option header active it will be open by default..you dont have to specify the option explicitly..just $('selector').accordion(); will do..

Answer (score 0):

var indexOfHeaderToBeOpened = 0;

$("#accordion").accordion('activate', indexOfHeaderToBeOpened);